# Hibernate filtering query collections

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I would like to ask if it's possible to do this using hibernate.
Let say I have already run a HQL and retrieved a collection. Is it possible to further filter it using hibernate?

I tried to use the `<filter>` to the header class and add session.enable() before the query, but seems it's not working.

Sample code

```
Query search = session.getNamedQuery(HQL_SOMEDEFAULTQUERY);
List results = search.list();
//further filtering ...
```

Stripped down HQL

```
select h
    from flow as f
    join f.item as i
    join i.header as h
    where i.status = :status
    and f.staff = :staff
    order by i.prId desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At least, not the way you asked. Once you ask Hibernate to hit the database (with the `list()` method), Hibernate did its part and the results are now in your hands. You can implement a filtering logic in your code to post-process the results.

That said, it is possible to filter the results *in* the query itself. If you define a Hibernate filter and enable it for a specific model/query, you'd be able to keep your original HQL query and Hibernate will append it with extra `where` clauses to further filter the results. See this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Comment: I have tried to use the session.enableFilter() method but seems it's not working. Probably because I am retrieving a collection. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The link mentioned by @partenon describes the usage of filters in detail. And no - it's not broken because you retrieve a collection. You most probably miss another part of the configuration.

Comment: I mean a header collection was retrieved but not a filtered collection. I was setting the filter in the header class but somehow it's not triggered using the HQL above. Should I place the filter in the item's header collection instead?

Comment: Seems like Hibernate does not allow me to place the filter in  the many to one relation. Any workaround? I just want to filter out some result that do not fulfill some extra conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The better way would be to use [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/index.html?org/hibernate//class-useQuery.html). Here is an example from [Hibernate Documentation that explains usage of Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

Criteria would be used before you call list method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have to use HQL instead of Criteria due to the complexity of the HQL_SOMEDEFAULTQUERY